# Webserver optimization in linux using pipe

Tags: optimization, linux-kernel, webserver, pipe

I have written a web server which reads the requested file and writes to the socket.
When I read the file I put the content of the file to the **user space** of OS and,
when I write it to the socket again I put the content to the **kernel space** of the operating system.

So I put it to the user space and again to the kernel space. This seems to be a waste of resources.

1. Isn't there a better option? Like directly sending to the kernel space rather than going through user space?
2. How can I optimize this process?
3. Can I use PIPE to optimize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try those, which can copy data from a file to a socket directly through kernel :

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile
- http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice

Comment: Thank u very much. Since the requested file and the socket are two file descrpters I can use sendfile(). I don't see any use of splice in my scenario. Am I right?